# Must I call parent::__construct() in the first line of the constructor?

Tags: php, oop

I know in Java, `super()` in a constructor has to be called as the first line of an overridden constructor.

Does this also apply to the `parent::__construct()` call in PHP?

I found myself writing an Exception class like this:

```
class MyException extends Exception {

  public function __construct($some_data) {

    $message = '';
    $message .= format_data($some_data);
    $message .= ' was passed but was not expected';

    parent::__construct($message);
  }

}
```

and I wondered if this would be considered an error/bad practice in PHP.

Comment: No it doesn't _have_ to be called as the first line. As you've found in your case, it often makes sense for it _not_ to be the first line.

Comment: If you google for anything PHP OOP related you will find http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php and in the first paragraph it has your answer.

Comment: Extending Exceptions is actually a good case in point where you might not want to call the parent constructor first; if you've rolled a multi-lingual custom Exception for instance - pass it the specific error code and it retrieves the message in the relevant language before passing it to the parent constructor... so no, it's not bad practice.

Comment: not a bad pratice

Comment: @DanielW. The doc page you provided doesn't answer the OP question. He wasn't asking whether he must call the parent constructor or not, he was asking if he can write other lines of code before calling the parent constructor.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want the code in the parent's constructor to be executed, you need to call `parent::__construct(…)` at some point. It does not technically matter *when* you do so. Sometimes it makes more sense to do a little work in the overridden constructor before calling the parent's constructor, sometimes you rely on work the parent's constructor does before you can do work in the overridden constructor.

As a rule of thumb I'd say you should call the parent's constructor *as soon as possible*. If you need to do something before you can call the parent's constructor, do so. If not, call it immediately. This is to avoid the parent's constructor undoing any of the work you're doing in the overridden constructor, like setting certain properties for example.

```
class A {
    function __construct() {
        $this->foo = 'bar';
    }
}

class B extends A {
    function __construct() {
        // parent::__construct();
        $this->foo = 'baz';
        // parent::__construct();
    }
}
```

In the above sample, the difference between calling the parent first or last makes a big difference in the resulting object. Which is more appropriate depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Accepting your answer because it's the highest voted and it seems good advice, although I would have wished for an answer elaborating on why whatever reasons lead to the rule in Java do not apply in PHP.

Comment: I cannot answer that because I don't know Java. In PHP, `__construct` is just like any other method, it merely does *something*, whatever you make it do, and it doesn't matter when you call it. The only special thing about it is that it's executed at object construction time.

Answer (score 1):

The main question is not whether the call to the parent constructor it should be executed on the first line, or executed at all. Instead it's about what can be considered better practice and why.

Doubling the given answers: yes, you can omit `parent::__construct` altogether; yes, you can call it from wherever you like inside the  `__construct` function of the child class. And any approach is good, as long as it **makes sense** and is **consistent**.

If you have a parent class with three children, for example, and every child uses the `parent::__construct` call in it's own way, then it *can* be a flag that the inheritence is not too clear and should be refactored.

Answer (score -3):

If you want to execute the code in the parent's constructor, then the answer is yes. If the child class overwrites the parent's constructor, you should omit it.

Comment: Missed the first line criteria, you can call it anywhere in the constructor's code.

Comment: This does not answer the initial question about **when** to call the parent's constructor